# how I can make react native counting Steps run on the background

Tags: react-native

i am trying to run counting steps on the background even when i kill the app but it not working any Idea how i should fix the code .
as result i can get the console
background started 2
Got background fetch call
but only one time and it supposed to run every so i dont know how i should implement this
Ps: am new in react native, please if anyone have suggestion i will be grateful. thanks

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";

import {

  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  ImageBackground,
  Dimensions,

} from "react-native";

import { Pedometer } from "expo-sensors";

import CircularProgress from "react-native-circular-progress-indicator";
// import backgont Task 
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
const requestActivityPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION,
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      Alert.alert("Start walking");
    } else {
      Alert.alert("permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};

export default function HomeScreen () {

  const [PedomaterAvailability, SetPedomaterAvailability] = useState("");

  const [StepCount, SetStepCount] = useState(0);
  const [Balance, SetBalance] = useState(0);
  const WindowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
  const Dist = StepCount / 1300;
  const DistanceCovered = Dist.toFixed(4);
  const cal = DistanceCovered * 60;
  const caloriesBurnt = cal.toFixed(4);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("the app has been started correct ")
    requestActivityPermission();
    subscribe();
    SetBalance(StepCount / 1000);
    registerBackgroundFetchAsync();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    SetBalance(StepCount / 1000)
    registerBackgroundFetchAsync();

  }, [StepCount]);

  subscribe = () => {
    const subscription = Pedometer.watchStepCount((result) => {
      SetStepCount(result.steps);
    });
    Pedometer.isAvailableAsync().then(
      (result) => {
        SetPedomaterAvailability(String(result));
      },
      (error) => {
        SetPedomaterAvailability(error);
      }
    );

  };
  const BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK = 'background-fetch';

  TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, async ()=> {
    console.log("background started 2")
    const now = StepCount;
    console.log(`Got background fetch call at date: ${now}`);
    return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.NewData;
  })

  async function registerBackgroundFetchAsync() {
    console.log("background Started")
    return BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, {
      minimumInterval:1, 
      stopOnTerminate: false, // android only,
      startOnBoot: true, // android only
    });
  }



  return (

    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        source={require("../../assets/BG.jpg")}
        resizeMode="cover"
      >
        <View style={{ marginTop: 30, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 20, color: "#f39c12", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
            Hello,Raouf!
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', fontSize: 20, color: "#f39c12", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
            Balence : {Balance}
          </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginTop: 30, justifyContent: "center" }}>
          <Text style={styles.headingDesign}>
            Is Pedometer available on the device : {PedomaterAvailability}
          </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginTop: 30, flex: 3, alignSelf: "center" }}>

          <CircularProgress
            value={StepCount}
            maxValue={6500}
            radius={150}
            textColor={"#ecf0f1"}
            activeStrokeColor={"#f39c12"}
            inActiveStrokeColor={"#4a15ad"}
            inActiveStrokeOpacity={0.5}
            inActiveStrokeWidth={20}
            activeStrokeWidth={40}
            title={"Step Count"}
            titleFontSize={25}
            titleColor={"#4a15ad"}
          />
          <View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-start" }}>
            <View >
              <Text style={styles.headingDesign} >
                Steps Count :{StepCount}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View >
              <Text style={styles.headingDesign} >
                Target : 6500 steps(5kms)
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View >
              <Text style={styles.headingDesign}>
                Distance Covered : {DistanceCovered} km
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View >
              <Text style={styles.headingDesign} >
                Calories Burnt : {caloriesBurnt}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <StatusBar hidden={false} backgroundColor="#b6a1de" translucent={true} />

          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>

  );

}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },

  headingDesign: {
    backgroundColor: "#4a15ad",
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },

  textDesign: {
    backgroundColor: "#4a15ad",
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 20,
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
    width: '85%',
    borderColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 20,
    overflow: "hidden",
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },

});
```